# i need dataTable.rows.update

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

```
 if (Variables.PolicyCustomers.ROL_ID === roleId && Variables.PolicyCustomers.CUSTOMER_ID=== customerCode) {
                    dataTable.rows.add([
                        customerCode,
                        name,
                        (taxNo.length > 0 ? taxNo : identityNo),
                        adress,
                        contact,
                        lotInput,
                        deleteButton,
                        updateButton
                    ]).draw(true);
```

In fact contact and address are changed but when i add like this anything is not change in row. they are not reflected to dataTable.

Comment: you should put edit more code here. are you sure `if (Variables.PolicyCustomers.ROL_ID === roleId && Variables.PolicyCustomers.CUSTOMER_ID=== customerCode) {` is true

Comment: yes i get true old row with this. but i dont know how can i update this row

Comment: i think you sould give more code. your syntax looks correct maybe there is a logic mistake